# Magento 2 order the simple search by name, not relevance

Tags: magento2

I have a project (Magento 2 site) where one of the requirements is to order the results of the search (using the search box in the top banner) by product name instead of the default 'relevance'. This doesn't appear to be as easy as changing the sort parameters for a category search which has configuration options in the XML files for that.
I've dug down into the search code but so far any attempts at altering the locations where 'relevance' is specified have resulted in no search results at all.

Any one know how to achieve this?

Comment: found any solution?

Answer (score -2):

You can change the "sort by" under: backend -> stores -> catalog -> catalog -> storefront. Set "Product Listing Sort by" to "Product Name".

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that seems to be for the ordering of the results when going through to a category. I'm looking for a way to stop the query search (using the search box and ending up on the ?q=whatever page) from sorting by relevance.